# Как рекурсивно пройти асоциативный массив и методом map для каждого элемента отрисовать <div> в React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

несколько дней не могу решить задачу.
Мне нужно пройтись рекурсией по этому массиву и для каждого елемента в "nodes"в Реакте и  отрисовать  с ключом "EXAMPLE.COM_192.168.0.1", потом "storage", "EXAMPLE.COM_192.168.0.1-storages-12" и т.д.

Буду благодарен за любую помощь.
P.S без jqwery

```
"nodes": {
  "EXAMPLE.COM_192.168.0.1": {
    "storage": [
      "EXAMPLE.COM_192.168.0.1-storages-12",
      "EXAMPLE.COM_192.168.0.1-storages-37",
      "EXAMPLE.COM_192.168.0.1-storages-41"
    ],
    "interfaces": [
      "EXAMPLE.COM_192.168.0.1-snmp-interfaces-eth0",
      "EXAMPLE.COM_192.168.0.1-snmp-interfaces-eth1",
      "EXAMPLE.COM_192.168.0.1-snmp-interfaces-br.lxc-4"
    ]
  },
  "Cisco3745new-1.SAMPLE.COM_192.168.0.120": {
    "interfaces": [
      "Cisco3745new-1.SAMPLE.COM_192.168.0.120-snmp-interfaces-eth0",
      "Cisco3745new-1.SAMPLE.COM_192.168.0.120-snmp-interfaces-eth1",
      "Cisco3745new-1.SAMPLE.COM_192.168.0.120-snmp-interfaces-eth2"
    ]
  },
  "Cisco3640new-1.SAMPLE.COM_192.168.0.180": {
    "interfaces": [
      "Cisco3640new-1.SAMPLE.COM_192.168.0.180-snmp-interfaces-eth0",
      "Cisco3640new-1.SAMPLE.COM_192.168.0.180-snmp-interfaces-eth1",
      "Cisco3640new-1.SAMPLE.COM_192.168.0.180-snmp-interfaces-eth2",
      "Cisco3640new-1.SAMPLE.COM_192.168.0.180-snmp-interfaces-eth3"
    ]
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Мне нужно пройтись рекурсией по этому массиву

Какому массиву? Вы имеете в виду массив nodes.EXAMPLE.COM_192.168.0.1.storage ?
Также не совсем понятно что вам именно нужно сделать с результатами? Отриосвать DOM элемент?

Вот пример кода. Входные данные:

```
const nodes = {
  'EXAMPLE.COM_192.168.0.1': {
    storage: [
      'EXAMPLE.COM_192.168.0.1-storages-12',
      'EXAMPLE.COM_192.168.0.1-storages-37',
      'EXAMPLE.COM_192.168.0.1-storages-41'
    ],
    interfaces: [
      'EXAMPLE.COM_192.168.0.1-snmp-interfaces-eth0',
      'EXAMPLE.COM_192.168.0.1-snmp-interfaces-eth1',
      'EXAMPLE.COM_192.168.0.1-snmp-interfaces-br.lxc-4'
    ]
  },
  'Cisco3745new-1.SAMPLE.COM_192.168.0.120': {
    interfaces: [
      'Cisco3745new-1.SAMPLE.COM_192.168.0.120-snmp-interfaces-eth0',
      'Cisco3745new-1.SAMPLE.COM_192.168.0.120-snmp-interfaces-eth1',
      'Cisco3745new-1.SAMPLE.COM_192.168.0.120-snmp-interfaces-eth2'
    ]
  },
  'Cisco3640new-1.SAMPLE.COM_192.168.0.180': {
    interfaces: [
      'Cisco3640new-1.SAMPLE.COM_192.168.0.180-snmp-interfaces-eth0',
      'Cisco3640new-1.SAMPLE.COM_192.168.0.180-snmp-interfaces-eth1',
      'Cisco3640new-1.SAMPLE.COM_192.168.0.180-snmp-interfaces-eth2',
      'Cisco3640new-1.SAMPLE.COM_192.168.0.180-snmp-interfaces-eth3'
    ]
  }

};
```

Решение. Вместо console.log(*) выполняйте то, что вам необходимо сделать со значением:

```
function recursiveObject(obj) {
  for (const prop in obj) {
    switch (typeof obj[prop]) {
      case 'object':
        console.log(prop);
        recursiveObject(obj[prop]);
        break;
      default:
        console.log(obj[prop]);
        break;
    }
  }
}
recursiveObject(nodes);
```

Comment: Спасибо, именно то что мне было нужно!